# Tensorflow Hub and JS: how to fine-tune a pre-trained model and export it for using in Tensorflow.js?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow.js, tensorflow-hub

I was trying to apply transfer learning with Tensorflow Hub and export the trained model to Tensorflow.js.

However, the exported trained model is only 2MB which is far from enough.

It seems that the Tensorflow Hub module is not exported. How can I export it?

```
def mobilenet_model_fn(features, labels, mode):
  module = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/mobilenet_v2_100_224/classification/2")
  input_layer = features['images']  # adjust_image(features["x"])
  outputs = module(input_layer)

  logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=outputs, units=4, name='hand_output')

  predictions = {
      # Generate predictions (for PREDICT and EVAL mode)
      "classes": tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1),
      # Add `softmax_tensor` to the graph. It is used for PREDICT and by the
      # `logging_hook`.
      "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="softmax_tensor")
  }

  if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
      return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=predictions)

  labels_converted = tf.argmax(labels, axis=-1)

  loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(
      labels=labels_converted, logits=logits)

  # Configure the Training Op (for TRAIN mode)
  if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
      optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
      train_op = optimizer.minimize(
          loss=loss,
          global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
      return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)

  # Add evaluation metrics (for EVAL mode)
  accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy(
      labels=labels_converted, predictions=predictions["classes"])
  eval_metric_ops = {"accuracy": accuracy}
  tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', accuracy[1])

  logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook({"loss": loss,
                                            "accuracy": accuracy}, every_n_iter=2)

  return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
      mode=mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops, training_hooks=[logging_hook])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use mobile net as your feature extractor. You have an example [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/tree/master/mobilenet) on how to use the pretrained mobilenet model